# Infinity Series problem with cos

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(3n+1)}{3^n},\quad (a_n)=\frac{\cos(3n+1)}{3^n}$$
I have to find out if it converges/diverges or not

My starting approach was that since $\cos(3n+1)<1 \implies \cos(3n+1)/3^n < 1/3^n$
then since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty1/3^n$ converges my sum will converge then I remembered that this criterion works for $a_n >0$ and obviously $-1<\cos(3n+1)<1$ making my approach wrong.

Could I have a hint about what criterion should I use here?

Comment: $|a_n| \le {1 \over 3^n}$.

Answer (score 3):

What you did shows that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\cos n}{3^n}\right|$ converges, and therefore that your series is absolutely convergent. So, it converges.

Answer (score 1):

You’re actually really close. Absolute convergence implies convergence, meaning that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |a_n|$ converges $\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ converges.

Comment: so that comes from the comparison criterion correct?